# ポートフォワードしたWEBサーバへのポート指定によるブラウザ接続

Tags: centos, network

[local PC] ↔ [踏み台Server] ↔ [WebServer]
※[WebServer]は閉ざされた環境

踏み台Serverから以下のポートフォワーディングし、
listened host … localhost:10100
connect host … xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80

ブラウザから　http://localhost:10100/　アクセスでapacheのdefault rootが表示される状態です。

で、今回、WebServerにWebApplicationを導入したのですが、xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888を指定してアクセスする仕組みとなっており、接続できずに行き詰ってしまいました。

このような場合、対処する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888 にリダイレクトされてしまうということでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCからWebサーバにアクセスすると、xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80にあるApacheのデフォルトのページを閲覧できるということですね。これを:8888につながるようにしたいので、「踏み台Server」の「connect host」を xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888 にすれば、Webアプリケーションにつながるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。connect hostを8888にすることで無事表示できました！